# Clob to String conversion

Tags: java, jdbc

```
if(resultSet.next())
      { 
        Reader r = resultSet.getClob(1). getCharacterStream();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int ch;
        while ((ch = r.read())!=-1) {
           buffer.append(""+(char)ch);
        }
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());
```

Question :
                  By doing above lines of code ,whether String be able to hold all data from the clob ?

Comment: Can the memory hold all the data?

Answer (score 0):

A String can hold a maximum of 2^31-1 characters. A Clob in MySQL can store up to 2^31-1 characters. Yes a String is able to hold all of the characters that Clob is comprised of.